# copy nsobject custom class to array after edit it's properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, nsarray

I do have a problem editing my custom class objects,
I do have a custom class of product,
when i pass it through next view where i can fix it's quantity and save it to my appdelegate array, everything OK!
But if I try to add the same product with another quantity to same array, first object get overwritten and i do get second object twice in my array with same property values,
my code is to messy to past it here, so here an pseudo example of problem:

```
view A: list of products

class product:
title
quantity

View B: product details
set quantity


let's say I choose product apple:
in view B quantity set to 2
added to array


if I select product apple again
set quantity to 1
added to array

as result I do get an array of 2 objects:
-apple quantity 1
-apple quantity 1
```

any help appreciated,

Comment: Post the relevant code causing the issue. Provide relevant info about any variables in the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario points out to a simple root cause: you are not making a copy of the object before editing it. The two objects in your `NSMutableArray` are actually the same object.

It is hard to identify the problem without seeing the relevant code. However, you need to make sure that the products and quantities are not stored in the same object:

```
@interface Product
@property NSString *name;
@property NSDecimal *price;
@end

@interface OrderEntry
@property Product *product;
@property int quantity;
@end
```

You should be adding `OrderEntry` objects to your `NSMutableArray`. Each time that you add a new entry a new `OrderEntry` object needs to be created, rather than modifying an existing one.

Comment: Thnx,
NSCOPY implemented at product class and problem solved.

Comment: @mamadoo That would work too. It may be a little suboptimal in terms of memory use, but since the number of copies is going to be in the dozens at the most, not in tens of millions, the difference is going to be insignificant.